# error: exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Tags: java

I receive an error each time. What am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
 public static void hashMap(String crnString)
{
    try
    {
        if (mMap.containsKey(crnString))
        {
            int count = mMap.get(crnString);
            count++;
            mMap.put(crnString, count);
        }
        else
        {
            mMap.put(crnString, 1);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: There is no 'syntax error' here. You 'receive an error' which is a *compile error,* and which *tells you* what's wrong. Don't just post 'I receive an error' here, without saying what it was: it's not acceptable; and don't just ignore what the error actually says. In this case, as in many, it already answers your question.

Comment: Sounds like you're having a bad day, have a better one tomorrow.

Comment: You need to supply the compilation error that you receive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `mMap` is a `HashMap`, the code inside the `try` block never throws an `IOException`. Remove the `try-catch` block wrapping your code.

```
public static void hashMap(String crnString){
    if (mMap.containsKey(crnString)) {
        int count = mMap.get(crnString);
        count++;
        mMap.put(crnString, count);
    } else {
        mMap.put(crnString, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I print the hashmap? Will this code work?

Comment: public static void printHash() {
  Iterator iter1 = mMap.entrySet().iterator();
  while(iter1.hasNext()){
   Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter1.next();
   System.out.println(mEntry.getKey()  +  " : " + mEntry.getValue());
   
   }
 }

Comment: @CPR That looks about right. Your best bet is to try it.

Answer (score 4):

IOException is checked exception. So code in try block is not potential code that can raise IOExcption that's why the compiler shows error. Use specific exception type catch block that can be raised or use unchecked exception catch block. In you try block code, only NPE can be raised.

```
  try
{
    if (mMap.containsKey(crnString))
    {
        int count = mMap.get(crnString);
        count++;
        mMap.put(crnString, count);
    }
    else
    {
        mMap.put(crnString, 1);
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Unexcepted Exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
}
```

Comment: Will this code work:  public static void printHash() {
  Iterator iter1 = mMap.entrySet().iterator();
  while(iter1.hasNext()){
   Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter1.next();
   System.out.println(mEntry.getKey()  +  " : " + mEntry.getValue());
   
   }
 }